# Render main presenter view in a specific div

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

For a GWTP based MVP a typical main presenter will be revealed with this code:

```
@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealRootContentEvent.fire(this, this);
}
```

This will render the View associated with the "main presenter" in the whole browser page. Is there any way for a main presenter's view to be rendered in a specific DIV in the page only. And not the whole page?

For example:

```
<div id="main-presenter"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [nested presenters](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/SimpleNestedSample)

```
@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this, MainPagePresenter.TYPE_SetMainContent,
            this);
}
```

Comment: I mean, the top most presenter to be rendered in a specific div, as opposed to being rendered in the whole page. I am using nested presenter already for my other presenter in my app, but I not sure what you mean by this